# In XSLT For-Each, How Do I Skip The Text Node?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a template that displays `text()` and then loops through all children and applies templates. The problem is that it is spitting the `text()` back on to the page which I already handled.

For the life of me, I cannot find the correct syntax for the `for-each select` to skip the text() node.

**Example XSLT Template**

```
<xsl:template match="Task">
<li>
  <u>
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
  </u>
  <ul>
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ul>
</li>
</xsl:template>
```

**Example XML**

```
<Task>
    This is my main task.
    <Task>
        This is a sub-task.
    </Task>
</Task>
```

**Example Undesired Output**

> - This is my main task.
>
>   - This is my main task.
>   - This is a sub-task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to replace

```
  <ul>
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ul>
```

with

```
  <xsl:if test="*">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:if>
```

Comment: You're a wizard! Thanks a lot, it worked great. I didn't even think about using the apply-templates to grab all the children. I was so stuck on looping myself.